# Why do i get invalid token "me",when i try to get user profile data from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making application which contains facebook login functionality and after login in facebook I want to get user's profile information.

So,My problem is i can successfully login in facebook but after login when i am trying to fetch user's profile I get **invalid token "me"** error from facebook.

**Use Code for this stuff is :**

```
    public void userLogin() {

        final LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        loginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            getProfileInformation(loginResult);
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "SuccessFull");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
}

public void getProfileInformation(LoginResult loginResult) {

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            Log.d("Error Message", response.getError().getErrorMessage());

            try {
                String userId = object.getString("id"); //getting error in this line
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("id", "id,name,link");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this Bundle parameter

```
parameters.putString("id", "id,name,link");
```

to

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
```

Comment: Uff, Thanks a lot. it works. Congo for review privilege.